# jQuery .text() values are empty - iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have really strange behavior with assigning the value to variable with jQuery. I can't get the values form .text(). Other functions on other sites work. Just Spotify is the problem. Even when elements are loaded it doesn't get stuff out.

function:

```
    function getTrackSpotify() {
    var track;

    track = $("#radio-artist .outgoing").text() + " - " + $("#radio-track .outgoing").text(); // both elements are empty. please check all code in pastebin.
    console.log(track);
    return track;
}
```

I am coding for 10 hours today, maybe my brains are just burned too much, and I can't see nothing..

HTML:

```
<div id="radio-track-info">
<h2 id="radio-track">
    <a class="outgoing" href="https://play.spotify.com/album/3g18ADJiQO3BNLIVZRENb1/track/04o7SCGvDEjIxinhTU4nxL/action/select">
  You See Me
</a>
</h2>
<h2 id="radio-artist">
    <a class="outgoing" href="https://play.spotify.com/artist/73sIBHcqh3Z3NyqHKZ7FOL">
  Childish Gambino
</a>
</h2>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's `$("#radio-track .outgoing").length` is giving you? Have u checked with console? And also, what's its content?

Comment: what's its content? plz share the html..

Comment: jsfiddle would be good

Comment: Did you know, you can assing this to a variable, not write it over and over again? :O `var elTrack = $("#radio-track .outgoing");`

Comment: I tried this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/2UJ72/1/) and it seems to work fine. I have used your JS code and HTML.

Comment: I updated my structure. Yeah I tried it on jsfiddle too and it works. Does that mean that Spotify somehow has an alghorithm that doesn't allow assigning to values from their site? Is that even possible? I don't think so.

Comment: Works perfectly fine when I paste your HTML to @Harry's fiddle, where are you calling getTrackSpotify() where it returns empty?

Comment: @JohnMathilda: Sorry, forget my previous question. You have mentioned that the alert works fine, so the data and elements are there. Wonderin where the issue could be

Comment: Yes it is called after DOM loads, because if it wasn't alert(get values from elements) wouldn't work, would it? That's why it is strange to me.

funkwurm I call it in another function, this is whole thing: http://pastebin.com/LYNLV617

As you can see I am doing this on other websites too, and works normal..

Comment: When you say "empty", does it have the hyphen from the `" - "`? Or is it `undefined`, or...? I take it there are no errors in the browser's JS console?

Comment: So it's a userscript to use in Greasemonkey and such? I would advice you to mention that next time because userscripts work a little different than plain javascript.

It also means I can't test this, but I notice you set the title with (effectively) `$('title').text(getWebsite());`. I've always had more luck doing `document.title = getWebsite();`, maybe in your case `window.document.title = getWebsite();` because of the Greasemonkey unsafeWindow passed to the wrapper function.

Comment: Got new info. I debugged this with firebug.. Check this: http://pastebin.com/56wu4Jyd .. value is assigned inside of if statement, but when I want to return it, it's undefined.

Comment: In this last update, you're updating from a setTimeout callback, which is asynchronous. So you are returning *before* the assignment.

Comment: Why do you have a `setTimeout` function in there?

Comment: I deleted that, I doesn't matter, the point is I don't know what is the problem... As you can see I have many sites, and I use same approach for each of them.. I think Spotify has some function that doesn't work properly with my code..

Comment: I removed setTimeout. I just want to say, that I don't understand why it gives me empty values from elements, while on all other websites I am parsing, I get the values out...

Comment: One thing that you're doing wrong is that in the `getWebsite()` function you're returning the results of the functions, not the function pointers themselves. So it should be `if(...) return getTrackSpotify;` (no parentheses at the end.)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Now I found out that In my console log I get 8 times undefined and twice I get the result which I want. http://i.imgur.com/8voVlQv.png which means that I get undefined in 80% and that's why I get empty string that I can't use. The length of the element I am accessing has length 0 when I get FUZE, and length 10, when I get undefined. Don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my advice is to inspect your DOM really hard. In my case I had 10 DOM Iframes, so I never could access to proper element. How I did it in the end:

```
    function getTrackSpotify() {
    var artist;
    var title;

    if($('#app-player').length > 0){
            artist = $('#app-player').contents().find("#player").find("#track-artist").text();
            title = $('#app-player').contents().find("#player").find("#track-name").text();
    }

    return (artist != '') ? artist + ' - ' + title + ' - Spotify' : 'Music for every moment - Spotify';
}
```

...where #app-player is id of iframe.

Cheers.